# Time unit expressed as a long float, what is it?

Tags: time

I'm contacting an API that returns a series of information. One of these, should be what I suppose to be a time unit and is expressed in a weird way:

```json
{
        "arrivalTime": 0.22916666666666746,
        "stopTimeDelta": 0.0138888888888889,
        "startTime": 0.24305555555555636
}
```

Has anybody ever seen something like this? I don't really need to use these dates for my project so that's why I don't bother contacting them, it's another company without straightforward channels to the dev team. But I'm really curious about this.

Comment: The documentation for the API you are using _should_ explain what this value is.

Comment: Looks like fractional days. I would guess that a value of 0.5 would be mid day i.e. 12PM with 0.25 being 6AM.

Comment: The documentation should have but didn't explain it. Anyway after some trial and errors it looks like as you say, with 1 as 24 hours, 0.5 12pm and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [@phuzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592958/phuzi) in the comments, it was fractional days. So, 1 is 24 hours, 0.25 is 6AM and so on.

This is a little function that will generate a Go time instance given the fractional unit.

[Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/IGZsdsdKWJ0)

```golang
func calculateTime(number float64) time.Time {
    today := time.Date(time.Now().Year(), time.Now().Month(), time.Now().Day(), 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    hour := number * 24
    minutes := (hour * 1440) / 24
    tm := today.Add(time.Duration(minutes) * time.Minute)

    return tm
}
```